# How/Where does nuxtjs set the authorization header

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, nuxt-auth

I inherited a web project from another developer who's left the company.  It is built with nuxtjs and laravel, neither of which I am strong with.

In the web project, after a user goes to a login screen, types in email and password, and presses save, I can see in my developer tools that the nuxtjs framework sends a `{email: "user@email.com", password: "password"}` to the laravel api at `https://example.project.com/api/login`.  The laravel api then returns a 200 response with this payload  `{ data: { message: "Login successful.", token: "50|Fs88RPU7HON1LnBskm35O9txG0OnXDiG3x4XWILJ" }}`. Everything is great so far!

Immediately after the 200 response above, NuxtJS sends another request to `https://example.project.com/api/auth/user` in an attempt to get information about this user.  Nginx gives a 401 response.  My first suspicion for why this happens is because NuxtJS sent an `Authorization: Bearer undefined` as shown in this screenshot of my browser dev tools
[image]

I've seen other situations with `Authorization: Bearer [object object]`.

**I want to know how does NuxtJS decide what value to provide to the `Authorization` http header?**  This is my current `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Blah',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png' }],
  },
  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/api/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/login'},
          user: { url: '/api/auth/user'}
        },
      }
    },
    localStorage: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://example.project.com/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    },
  },


  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://example.project.com/',
    credentials: true,
    headers : {
      common: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

And also, this is the line of code in `pages/login.vue` that starts the login process:

```
await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: {email:"user@email.com",password:"password"} });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `Authorization` header as default header right after authorization request. Assuming that server sends access token in response the code might look like this:

```
const response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { 
  data: {
    email: "user@email.com",
    password:"password"
  } 
})
const { token } = response;
axios.defaults.headers.common = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
```

Comment: I updated my question to show that the code uses `await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: {email:"user@email.com",password:"password"} });` .  So the token is being captured behind the scenes by `nuxtjs`.  I'm not sure how to handle the magic behind the scene of nuxtjs

Comment: I checked the docs, ```loginWith``` returns server's response. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

change your strategy as below to set property name of the token being returned in response.

```
strategies: {
  local: {
    token: {
      property: 'token'
    },
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: '/api/login'},
      user: { url: '/api/auth/user'}
    },
  }
},
```

It will include the authorization header in all your requests using `$axios`.

also you might need to set propery of the **user** which you are returning from backend also.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in my question and updated to say that `/api/login` returns `{data: {message: "...etc...", token: "50|Fs88RPU7HON1LnBskm35O9txG0OnXDiG3x4XWILJ"}}` .  So I changed my strategy to have `strategies.local.token.property == "data.token"` .  Is `data.token` the proper way to specify a nested property name?  Because right now this causes nuxt/axios to send `Authorization: Bearer [object Object]`

Comment: actually, the solution was to use you the `strategies` tha tyou posted, but just make the `login:` to `login: { url: '/api/login', propertyName: 'data.token'}`

Answer (score 0):

This is done by a library in the background. `@nuxtjs/auth` or `@nuxtjs/auth-next` will set the token [depending on your config](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local) in `nuxt.config.ts`.

You can find the token in the local storage in `auth._token.<strategy>`. To use a Bearer token in the subsequent `userinfo` request you might need to set:

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      token: {
        type: 'Bearer',
      }
    }
  }
```